# SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG with rstudio-server on AWS

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate-errors

I installed [rstudio-server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/) on an AWS EC2 instance.  Everything went well, but when trying to access `https://myawsserver.example.org:8787` I get the following error :

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to XX.XX.XX.XX:8787. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

I cannot find any issue in the logs or anywhere.  What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RStudio Server Open Source Edition doesn't support SSL encryption, [this is a feature](https://www.rstudio.com/products/RStudio/) of the Commercial License version.

Try accessing `http://myawsserver.example.org:8787` (HTTP instead of HTTPS) and you should get to your RStudio login page.